# Excel: Get average task length per date

Tags: excel, date, average, countif

I have some tasks with start and end date given as this:
[image]

And I want to calculate the active work in progress per day as well as the average work length for the active tasks per day. The current WIP I was able to calculate as shown in the B2 formula:

[image]

But how would I calculate the average work length of all active tasks with a similar formula for C2:C7? (I provided the expected results with a reason as well in the picture above)

Here's the example as a csv (will be imported as one sheet though):

```
Task,start date,end date,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T1,25.06.2018,26.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T2,25.06.2018,25.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T3,26.06.2018,28.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T4,26.06.2018,27.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T5,26.06.2018,26.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T6,26.06.2018,28.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T7,27.06.2018,27.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
T8,27.06.2018,29.06.2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,Day,Tasks in progress,average active task length (eod),,expected result,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,24.06.2018,0,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,25.06.2018,1,,,1,  at the end of 25th 1 task was active and running for 1 day (T1),,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,26.06.2018,3,,,1,"  at the end of 26th 3 tasks were active and each running for 1 day (T3,T4 and T6)",,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,27.06.2018,3,,,1.66,"  at the end of 27th 3 tasks were active and running for: 2d (T3), 2d (T6) and 1d (T8)",,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,28.06.2018,1,,,2,  at the end of 28th 1 task was active and running for 2 days (T8),,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,29.06.2018,0,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: The part where you say *...and running for X days(Task Number)...*, you are concatenating different tasks id. I don't think you can accomplish to get that in each row using pure Excel. Probably you will need VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array formula
in B2:

```
=SUM(IF(Tasks!$B$2:$B$9<=A2;1;0)*IF(Tasks!$C$2:$C$9>=A2;1;0))
```

and accept formula <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

EDIT: C2 formula not added

```
=AVERAGE(IF(IF(Tasks!$B$2:$B$9<=A2;1;0)*IF(Tasks!$C$2:$C$9>=A2;1;0)=1;Tasks!$C$2:$C$9-Tasks!$B$2:$B$9;""))
```

and accept formula <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

EDIT2: C2 formula after consultations

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(IF(Tasks!$B$2:$B$9<=A2;1;0)*IF(Tasks!$C$2:$C$9>A2;1;0)*IF((Tasks!$C$2:$C$9-Tasks!$B$2:$B$9)>0;1;0)=1;A2-Tasks!$B$2:$B$9+1;""));0)
```

accept formula <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the formula for B2 is visible in the screenshot and your formula for C2 doesn't work for me (I get a #DIV/0) even after fixing it to {=AVERAGE(IF(IF(Tasks!$B$2:$B$9<=A2,1,0)*IF(Tasks!$C$2:$C$9>=A2,1,0)=1,Tasks!$C$2:$C$9-Tasks!$B$2:$B$9,""))}

Comment: sorry "Jeżeli" in polish language is "IF" - I have "polish" excel. Maybe if you add function if error  then will be good -> {=iferror( average(...); 0) }

Comment: Hi, I tried it but all cells C2:C9 have errors so they're all 0 with the IFERROR(,0). I also uploaded a csv 1-sheet-version in the description. If you'd like you could play around if your formula works for you?

Comment: i send  here    http://www.filedropper.com/tasks_4       my file - maybe that help

Comment: Hi, thanks for that file - somehow Excel isn't able to convert local date-formats to the ones internally used - once I reformated the dates to American standard your formula works. However, you just take the average of the total tasks-length that are active for that day (i.e. C2:C9 - B2:B9 ) but I need the current ongoing average up to this date, that is: If a task length is 3 days but we're only after 2 days then this task contributes to 2 days to the average (not 3). Do you see a way to get the "expected results" described above?

Comment: I edit answer - that formula calculate correctly - results are the same as "expected results"

Comment: Very nice - thanks a lot for your help and patience! :-)